# Pressure on a sample of fluid due to the molecules to the side of the sample

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

### Question 1

Consider a sample at a height $h$ below the interface of air and the fluid. The pressure on the sample is given by $P_a =P_{atm} + \rho gh$ .

My question is does $P_a$ include the pressure due to the particles that are to the side of the sample?[image]

---

### Question 2

Now consider this setup.

[image]

In this setup the two samples, say $A$ and $B$, must experience same pressure i.e. $P_a = P_b$ due to **Pascals law**. But the column of molecules above the sample is different. Isn't? Above B there are less number of molecules. On the other hand, above A there are more number of molecules and also $P_{atm}$ adds to it. Due to this, the $P_a$ > $P_b$. But this isn't the case. When I asked this question to my teacher, he said that around the sample $B$ there are particles to the left that also exert pressure on it due to which $P_a = P_b$.

If this it true, then doesn't particles to the side of Sample $A$ also exert pressure on A?

I asked the first question because of the second question.

Comment: This is just a guess, but for your second question; don’t you think a liquid’s ability to transfer pressure could explain why there is equal pressure on A and B?

Comment: @UbaidHassan What about the molecules around A? Doesn't it also transmit pressure to A? If the pressure is transmitted to B and $P_a = P_b$, then why can't pressure from the molecules around A transmit pressure to A, increasing pressure on A and hence making $P_a ≠ P_b$. Are you able to understand what I'm trying to ask?

Comment: The horizontal pipe wall above B is exerting a pressure downward on the column of molecules above B.  This is just enough to make the pressure at B the same as at A.

Comment: So it isn't because of the pressure exerted by the molecules to the side? Moreover, is $P_{wall} = P_{atm}$? If yes, then the pressure exerted by the column of water molecules on B is less. So as $P_{A column}$ (column of water molecules above A) $> P_{B column}$ (column of water molecules above B). Isn't? So this again bring a pressure difference between these two samples.